# Vector equation $\mathbf{x}= \mathbf{ a}-(\mathbf{b} \cdot \mathbf{x}) \mathbf{b} - \mathbf{b} \times \mathbf{x}$

Tags: vectors

A friend of mine has just sent me this question and I have no idea how to go about solving it. Here it is:
The vector $\mathbf{x}$ satisfies the equation $\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{a} - (\mathbf{b} \cdot \mathbf{x}) \mathbf{b} - \mathbf{b} \times \mathbf{x}$
Show that $\mathbf{x} \cdot \mathbf{b} = \frac{\mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{b}}{1+\lvert \mathbf{b} \rvert^2}$, and hence solve the equation for $\mathbf{x}$.
It's been a while since I've done anything with vectors so I'm not very good with the identities, can someone offer a solution?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Just dot both sides with $\mathbf{b}$, and the identity follows immediately.

Comment: @HosamHAJEER: when you dot both sides with $b$, you get an easy expression for $bx$, but this does not give you a solution for $x$ (it's not that you can divide by $b$ :-) ).

Comment: @HosamHAJEER any idea where to go from here with regard to finding an explicit solution for $\mathbf{x}$?

Comment: @GTBailey Yes. I've just posted a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, to prove the identify, dot both sides of the equation with $\mathbf{b}$.  This gives

$\mathbf{b} \cdot \mathbf{x} = \mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{b} - (\mathbf{b} \cdot \mathbf{x} ) (\mathbf{b} \cdot \mathbf{b} ) $

The third term on the right hand side drop because $\mathbf{b} \times \mathbf{x}$ is orthogonal to $\mathbf{b} $.

From this, we now have

$ ( 1 + \mathbf{b} \cdot \mathbf{b} ) ( \mathbf{b} \cdot \mathbf{x} ) = \mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{b}  $

Therefore,

$ \mathbf{b} \cdot \mathbf{x} = \dfrac{ \mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{b} }{ 1 + \mathbf{b} \cdot \mathbf{b} } $

This proves the identity.

Now to solve for $\mathbf{x}$, construct a basis for $\mathbf{R}^3$ composed of the vectors $ \mathbf{a}, \mathbf{b}, \mathbf{a \times b} $

Then we can express $\mathbf{x}$ as follows

$ \mathbf{x} = c_1 \ \mathbf{a} + c_2 \ \mathbf{b} + c_3 \
 (\mathbf{a \times b }) $

The right hand side becomes

$ \mathbf{a} - \mathbf{b} (  c_1 (\mathbf{a \cdot b}) + c_2 (\mathbf{b \cdot b} )) - c_1 \mathbf{b} \times \mathbf{a} - c_3 \ \mathbf{b} \times (\mathbf{a \times b} )  $

Using the triple product rule, we have

$ \mathbf{ b } \times ( \mathbf{a \times b} ) = \mathbf{a} (\mathbf{b \cdot b} ) - \mathbf{b} ( \mathbf{ a \cdot b} ) $

Therefore, putting all together

$ c_1 \ \mathbf{a} + c_2 \ \mathbf{b} + c_3 \
 (\mathbf{a \times b })  = \mathbf{a} - \mathbf{b} (  c_1 (\mathbf{a \cdot b}) + c_2 (\mathbf{b \cdot b} )) -  c_1 \mathbf{b} \times \mathbf{a} - c_3 (\mathbf{a} (\mathbf{b \cdot b} ) - \mathbf{b} ( \mathbf{ a \cdot b} ) )$

Comparing coefficients, we deduce that

$ c_1 = 1 - c_3 (\mathbf{b \cdot b} ) $

$ c_2 = - (  c_1 (\mathbf{a \cdot b}) + c_2 (\mathbf{b \cdot b} )) +c_3 (\mathbf{a \cdot b} )$

$ c_3 = c_1 $

Substituing the last equation into the first gives us

$ c_1 = \dfrac{ 1 }{ 1 + \mathbf{b \cdot b } } $

And substituting into the second equation gives us

$  c_2 = - c_2 ( \mathbf{b \cdot b} ) $

which implies that $c_2 = 0 $

Therefore, the solution for $\mathbf{x} $ is

$ \mathbf{x} = \dfrac{ \mathbf{a} + \mathbf{a \times b } } {1 + \mathbf{ b \cdot b}} $

One can show that this formula holds even if $ \mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$ are linearly dependent.  In this case we will have

$ \mathbf{x} = \dfrac{\mathbf{a}}{1 + \mathbf{b \cdot b} } $